# How do I export a conda environment? (command seems not to be working)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I would like to export a conda environment, so that I can use it on another PC. I found this:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/user-guide/tasks/work-with-environments/

And used the command that is in there, in the command promt opened via the anaconda navigator as follows: `conda env export --name root -f root.yml`. No feedback was given, and the root.yml file seems nowhere to be found.

After looking on stackoverflow, I found the command `conda env export > root.yml`. However, still no feedback is given, and the root.yml file is also missing. Running only `conda env export` gives a list of the name, channels, dependencies, and prefix. However, still no yml file to export.

I have the following versions:

```
 conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing the correct thing. Are you sure you have write permissions in the location you are saving to? Also, note that the answer you accepted is suggesting you output a `requirements.txt` not a YAML (it just names it `.yml`). Generally, the YAML output is to be preferred, so it would be better to continue using `conda env export`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this command:

```
conda list --name root --export > root-env.txt
```

This is one of the recommended methods for saving an environment spec.  List the contents in a known format that conda can reuse (the `--export` flag) and then write to a file using the `>` operator.

The exported file will be in whatever directory you are running the command from.  I.e. running:

```
C:\Users\hello>conda list --name root --export > root-env.txt
```

Will save the file to

```
C:\Users\hello\root-env.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't give any feedback either. I searched the `C:\...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3` for .yml files, but still no root.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question & answer, I also just faced the same problem recently. I post my experience in case it helps others currently facing this issue.

When using the command:

```
conda env export --from-history
```

(or any option following `conda env`) I would get only a `[y/N]:` in the output and no response.

I found two solutions to solve the issue:

- conda must itself be installed in that environment (calling it from the base environment results in the empty prompt response)
- upgrading conda from 4.13.0 to 4.14.0 (in that environment) `conda update conda`